# merging client and server package.json files into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json

I have a project that consists of server side code (in nodejs) and client side code (with react). I have separate package.json files for those but I was asked to merge them into one. Server file is in the project root dir, client side is in /client folder with the rest of client code. Could you help me to do that? May I just copy client file to server client with some modification? I cannot find anything useful on it.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "curr-calc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "currency calc using node.js and react.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "babel": "babel --presets es2015 js/server.js -o build/main.bundle.js",
    "test": "yarn --cwd client run test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && yarn --production=false && yarn run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react-widgets": "^4.2.6",
    "redis": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.3.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^6.3.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

client/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "curr-calc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^6.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

EDIT:

I tried to merge this manually:
1) I copied all dependencies
2) I copied srcipts and renamed those duplicated and add "cd client && " to the beginning of every client script 
3) I removed package.json, node_modules and all yarn files from clien folder

Now when I try to run the app by yarn dev I receive:

> Listening on port 5000 [1] module.js:549 [1]     throw err; [1]     ^
>   [1]  [1] Error: Cannot find module
>   '/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/client/package.json' [1]
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15) [1]     at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25) [1]     at Module.require
>   (module.js:596:17) [1]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18) [1]
>   at getPublicUrl
>   (/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js:34:19)
>   [1]     at Object.
>   (/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js:61:14)
>   [1]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) [1]     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10) [1]     at
>   Module.load (module.js:565:32) [1]     at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12) error An unexpected error occurred: "Command
>   failed. [1] Exit code: 1 [1] Command: sh [1] Arguments: -c cd client
>   && react-scripts start [1] Directory:
>   /home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc [1] Output: [1] ". info If
>   you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information
>   provided in "/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/yarn-error.log".
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about
>   this command. error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed. [1]
>   Exit code: 1 [1] Command: sh [1] Arguments: -c yarn start [1]
>   Directory: /home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc [1] Output: [1] ".
>   info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the
>   information provided in
>   "/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/yarn-error.log". info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command. [1] yarn client exited with code 1
>   --> Sending SIGTERM to other processes.. [0] yarn server exited with code null error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed. Exit
>   code: 1 Command: sh Arguments: -c concurrently --kill-others-on-fail
>   \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\" Directory:
>   /home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc Output: ". info If you think
>   this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided
>   in "/home/zaba/code/currCalc_react/curr-calc/yarn-error.log".

Why is it still looking for client/package.json file? Can that be create-react-app setting hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I would not merge those into one. They are two different applications and have different dependencies. I'd namespace the names though like this:  `@curr-calc/client` and `@curr-calc/server`.

If you really wanted to merge them, I'd do that manually by just copying over the dependencies, devDependencies and scripts. Remove any duplicates (in case of scripts you'll need to rename those who have duplicate keys).

Comment: It's not my choice here actually. Thank you for tips!

Comment: I tried merging them manually but that doesn't work. yarn complains about scripts. Is it important in that case that the app was generated with create-react-app?

Comment: What exactly is yarn complaining about? You have to rename the scripts that have the same key (eg. "test")

Comment: I renamed them. Still when trying to run the app by yarn dev it looks for client/package.json. I removed package.json, all yarn files and node modules from client folder. I edit my question with everything I did and console output.

Comment: In your script "client" you change directory into your client folder. You have to adjust the scripts so that the correct scripts are called. In this case you could just delete the "client" script and call the renamed start script from you client directly in your "dev" script.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention that the scripts in your package.json are just calling terminal commands. So you have to adjust those to your new project structure.

Comment: I understand that. But I cannot make my 'yarn start' script get to work in new config. From root dir it looks for a build folder under root instead of client; run from client it looks for client/package.json. I think it is configuration from react-srcipt module making problem here.

Comment: Sure, you'll have to move your folder structure up. everything under ./client needs to be under ./
That's one of the reasons I wouldn't recommend splitting the package.json.

Comment: Or you need to eject your app and take care of the configuration yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches here, depending on your goals:

1. Merge it manually, along with the two projects - then you'll have a single project with a single `package.json` file.
2. Since json is just a plain JS object, you can use something like lodash's [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#merge) to achieve that:

   ```
   const server = require("../path/to/server/package.json");

   const client = require("../path/to/client/package.json");

   const merge = require("lodash/fp/merge");

   let merged = merge(server, client);
   ```

more information about lodash-fp and node can be found [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide)

Comment: Is it important in these approaches that my app is created with create-react-app?

I tried to merge them manually (and as far as I checked all merge-package modules do basically the same) but that doesn't work - yarn is not happy about scripts...

Comment: That shouldn't matter, and as a good practice, you should [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) from it as soon as you can.

Comment: how to do that? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I've attached a link in my previous comment